# Совет по оптимальной верстке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Прошу совета,как лучше всего сверстать такой блок с возможностью адаптивности - на дивах или таблицей? Пробовала на дивах, очень геморно получается и ко всему прочему она не очень адаптивна. Таблица тоже довольно проблематичная получается.

Не могу понять,какой из этих способов менее проблематичный ) Код писать за меня не прошу, просто подскажите наиболее оптимальный вариант для такого вида

Спасибо заранее[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, который я писала на дивах (не полный, т.к. полный был удален в угаре чистки и сейчас я переписываю).

```css
.promo {
 border-left: 5px solid red;
}
.promo h1 {
 font-size: 2.5em;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.gender {
 border-left: 2px solid red;
}
.gender p {
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin: 0 0 5px 15px;
}
.men {
 display: inline-block;
}
.men p:first-child {
 font-size: 1.15em;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.women {
 display: inline-block;
}
.women p:first-child {
 font-size: 1.15em;
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.men img {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
.women img {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
     <div class="promo about">
  <div ><h1>Аудитория</h1></div>
  </div>
     <div class="gender">
  <p>Пол</p>
     <div class="men"><p><img src="men.jpg" alt="">Мужчины</p>
     <p>50%</p>
     </div>
     <div class="women"><p><img src="w.jpg" alt="">Женщины</p>
     <p>50%</p>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Какая может быть проблематичность в дивах? И конечно если говорить об адаптивности, то это сразу дивы. Покажите что вы сверстали

Comment: Добавила в вопрос. И да, он, мягко говоря, не очень )

Comment: Вы не правильно подходите к верстке. Сначала сверстайте 2 блока, левый и правый, сделайте стили так, что на мелких разрешениях, блоки четко заполняли пространство. Не нужно городить внутри этих блоков информацию до того, как не разобрались с внешней структурой. Идите поэтапно. А ответ от Юрия вам поможет в этом. Помните идите *сверху вниз*. И тут нет ничего сложного, большое количество кода появляется когда много элементов, от этого не уйти. Но можно упросить разбив на подстраницы в каком нибудь билд проекте для интерфейса

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется, что для вашей задачи лучше использовать `div` и делать его оптимальным с помощью `flexbox`. Это позволит вам редактировать любые размера блока, как вам удобно. При том сейчас таблицы редко используют для таких целей, так как современные стили полностью и прекрасно выполняют всю эту работу и делают её более удобнее.

Что бы сделать блоки гибкими используйте `@media` или величины `vw` и `vh`. Это позволит блокам подстраиваться под любые размеры экрана